# Progress of heavy php using sessions

Tags: php, ajax, session, progress

I'm doing some heavy image manipulation in php and I would like to show the user how things are progressing. So I tried doing something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['progress'] = $i/ $rowCount;
     session_write_close();

     processLine($i);
}
```

And then I'm using AJAX calls to another php file which basically returns the value of $_SESSION['progress']. Problem is, it is not set. Is this because you shouldn't start a session more than once per file? If I just open the session and don't close it between each row, the SESSION variable is locked and my polling file won't be handled until the whole image manipulation is done.

Any way to get this to work using sessions? I think it might work if I put the progress in a database or file, but that's slow and we'll have to do a bit of work to identify users (using ips or session ids). Using sessions would take care of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because php locks the session file. The first process that still uses the same session locks the file, the ajax call uses the same session ID, thus trying to access the same session file but it can't since it is locked by php until the first process finishes up.

This is the answer to your question. If you want to know how to fix it, I am not sure, I have to think about it.

Comment: Yea, I figured that being the problem. So you cannot unlock the session in the process, so that other processes may use it to check in on progress?

Comment: No. I would look for a different approach. For example. create some temp file, maybe named after the image name being processed. Then save progress into that temp file. Then Ajax will have to access another php file like checkstatus.php?f=filename

Comment: Also if you use memcache, its even better and faster to save progress result into memcache, it will just be faster than using temp file.

Comment: This memcache thing sounds interesting, I will look into it ;-) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've run some basic test with memcache and it looks very promising.. will keep you guys posted!

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, you should just have the `session_start();` function at the very top of each PHP script that uses functions and only that one. Remove all other session_start's and all the other session functions you may have like `session_write_close();`.

Do not close sessions or use anything else as it is not required. If the value is not returning you might want to double check the JavaScript console in-browser to check for returned PHP errors or for files named error_log in your file's directory.

Otherwise everything should work just as expected. I have done similar types of things in the past and it worked just fine. I hope this helps you debug your issues.

Comment: No, this won't solve my problems actually. Because two php files cannot work on the same session at the same time :( I cannot read the value of the progress variable while I am still doing my image manipulation this way..

Comment: That is strange since you should be able to have the same session opened twice to read/write unless it won't update the session value globally until the image manipulation script has finished executing. Maybe try to start the session and set that variable to a 0 percentage before the image manipulation script beings to execute. Might be something to try if you haven't already.